# Do page tables used to store kernel stack pointer when context switch happen in kernel mode of the process?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, memory-management

I have two questions;

1. Suppose a user space application/process is running in kernel mode. I understand if a context switch is happened now, the kernel stack pointer of that process is stored in the `task_struct`. Is that correct? For that, do a `PTE` (page table entry) created in the page table to map the `Kernel Stack Pointer` (which is a `Virtual address`) to the `Physical Address`?
2. In the case of a `kthread`, does it have a page table to support context switch?

Answer (score 0):

Any virtual address can only be used if the area of memory it points to has a corresponding page table entry. A process running in kernel mode uses its kernel stack, so a PTE already exists before any context switch needs to be handled.

No additional PTE is required to *store* a pointer, unless a new memory area is needed to store the pointer (which isn’t the case here).